# Dictionary Class in Ruby from TestFirst.org

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I'm trying to solve the Dictionary problem from TestFirst.org. The goal is to get my codes to work with the test spec. Apparently I am getting the `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for nil: NilClass`

I  post the my codes and test spec below.

It looks like the test can not read my add and keywords methods for some reasons. Can someone help me determine why it is behaving that way?

My codes:

```
class Dictionary
    #initialization of entries
    def entries
        @hash = {}
    end

    def add(keyvalue)
        keyvalue.each do |key, value|
            @hash[key] = value  #create key-value pair in @hash
        end
    end

    def keywords
        key_array = []
        @hash.each {|key,value| key_array.push(key)}    #push key inside key_array
    end

end
```

Test Spec:

```
require '11_dictionary'

describe Dictionary do   
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new   
  end

  it 'is empty when created' do
    @d.entries.should == {}   
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']   
  end

  it 'add keywords (without definition)' do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => nil}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']   
  end

  it 'can check whether a given keyword exists' do
    @d.include?('fish').should be false   
  end

  it "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists" do
    @d.include?('fish').should be false # if the method is empty, this test passes with nil returned
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fish').should be true # confirms that it actually checks
    @d.include?('bird').should be false # confirms not always returning true after add   
  end

  it "doesn't include a prefix that wasn't added as a word in and of itself" do
    @d.add('fish')
    @d.include?('fi').should be false   
  end

  it "doesn't find a word in empty dictionary" do
    @d.find('fi').should be_empty # {}   
  end

  it 'finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing' do
    @d.add('fiend')
    @d.add('great')
    @d.find('nothing').should be_empty   
  end

  it "finds an entry" do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.find('fish').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}   
  end

  it 'finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('fiend' => 'wicked person')
    @d.add('great' => 'remarkable')
    @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}   
  end

  it 'lists keywords alphabetically' do
    @d.add('zebra' => 'African land animal with stripes')
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('apple' => 'fruit')
    @d.keywords.should == %w(apple fish zebra)   
  end

  it 'can produce printable output like so: [keyword] "definition"' do
    @d.add('zebra' => 'African land animal with stripes')
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('apple' => 'fruit')
    @d.printable.should == %Q{[apple] "fruit"\n[fish] "aquatic animal"\n[zebra] "African land animal with stripes"}   
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because every test block executes separately, so, for example, in `can add whole entries with keyword and definition` you execute:

```
@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
```

but `@hash` instance variable in `@d` object is uninitialized. To fix it, you should initialize `@hash` upon object initialization:

```
class Dictionary
  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def entries
    @hash
  end
  # etc.
end
```

or, instead of operating directly on `@hash` instance variable, you can create private accessor:

```
class Dictionary
  def entries
    hash
  end

  def keywords
    key_array = []
    hash.each {|key,value| key_array.push(key)}    #push key inside key_array
  end
  # etc.
  private

  def hash
    @hash ||= {}
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. Also I find it interesting that the `add` method accepts a parameter of the form `key=>value` but I cannot do that if I name it as a variable. For example, I can't do `test = "test" => "value"`. I tried creating a method on repl.it and takes in a parameter of the form `key=>value`, it converts to a hash immediately. For example, if i define `def test(para) t end` then then call it `test("test" => "value")`, I get a hash. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: @Guy because in assignment, if you assign hash, you should wrap it in `{}`, because otherwise it could lead to inconsistencies, I guess.

Comment: You are right. Somehow I over think it. I was doing `("t"=>"b").each { |key,value| puts key + " "+value}` but it didn't work and that got me to overthink. It should have been `{...}` I was thinking about the parenthesis in the method.

Comment: I am onto the last test which is to create `printable` method to satisfy the condition but my method does not seem to work due to the error described. Can you help me?

Comment: I editted my code and pasted the completed code. I could not get the `printable` method to work to meet the test. I am getting `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Array` error. How would you fix that?

Comment: @Guy this question is completely different, so you should add another question in SO instead of editing this one. I rolled back the question to the previous form.